# Launching Genymotion invokes a NullPointerException

Tags: plugins, android-studio, nullpointerexception, emulation, genymotion

I actually installed the genymotion plugin in android studio and started the genymotion device manager.

Then it said the path isn't specified, so I specified the path to genymotion ( C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion ). After that the error happens again -
`NullPointerException` on opening `genymotion`. This image shows the error:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/fP1JqS1.jpg]

Answer (score 1):

I think i found out the answer. My computer does not support VT-X. So obviously genymotion cant run. Also genymotion needs virtual box to run over.